# Count how many elements in a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with span inside of it. Is there a way of counting how many elements in a div then give it out as a value. For Example there were 5 span in a div then it would count it and alert five. In Javascript please.

Thank you.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381296/best-way-to-get-child-nodes) might prove useful

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use this function, it will avoid counting TextNodes.
You can choose to count the children of the children (i.e. recursive)

```
function getCount(parent, getChildrensChildren){
    var relevantChildren = 0;
    var children = parent.childNodes.length;
    for(var i=0; i < children; i++){
        if(parent.childNodes[i].nodeType != 3){
            if(getChildrensChildren)
                relevantChildren += getCount(parent.childNodes[i],true);
            relevantChildren++;
        }
    }
    return relevantChildren;
}
```

Usage:

```
var element = document.getElementById("someElement");
alert(getCount(element, false)); // Simply one level
alert(getCount(element, true)); // Get all child node count
```

Try it out here:
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsgXs/)

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. If this solves the issue don't forget to mark it as the answer. If you need further explanation of how it works let me know.

Answer (score 54):

If you want the number of descendants, you can use

```
var element = document.getElementById("theElementId");
var numberOfChildren = element.getElementsByTagName('*').length
```

But if you want the number of immediate children, use

```
element.childElementCount
```

See browser support here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljsfamht.php

or

```
element.children.length
```

See browser support here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.children#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 9):

Without jQuery:

```
var element = document.getElementById("theElementId");
var numberOfChildren = element.children.length
```

With jQuery:

```
var $element = $(cssSelectocr);
var numberOfChildren = $element.children().length;
```

Both of this return only immediate children.

Comment: This will fail when there are nested elements in the div.

Comment: The question is not clear about that, I assumed only first children.

Answer (score 4):

i might add just stupid and easy one answer

```
<div>this is div no. 1</div>
<div>this is div no. 2</div>
<div>this is div no. 3</div>
```

you can get how many divs in your doc with:

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
console.log(divs.length) // 3
```

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery you can do like this:

```
var count = $('div').children().length;
alert( count );​​​
```

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dryYq/1/

Comment: This will fail when there are nested elements in the div

Comment: Where in the question do you see that the OP is using jQuery?

Comment: @jfriend00 I didn't, but as this was a javascript question, I thought that a jQuery answer could fit, if the questioner happened to use jQuery.

Comment: The general mode on StackOverflow is that you only propose a jQuery answer if the question is tagged with jQuery.  Otherwise, you do plain javascript (not using pre-built libraries).  In otherwords, if the OP wants jQuery answers, they tag the question as such.  If not, we assume plain javscript.

Comment: @user1572008 Nice to here. If you like it, please mark it as an Accepted Answer :)

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery; checks only for spans inside a div:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/FfcFM/)

```js
$(function(){
    var numberOfSpans = $('#myDiv').children('span').length;
    alert(numberOfSpans);
})();​
```

Comment: This isn't a jQuery question.

Comment: Downvoted for JQuery

Answer (score 2):

To count all descendant elements including nested elements in plain javascript, there are several options:

The simplest is probably this:

```
var count = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("*").length;
```

If you wanted the freedom to add more logic around what you count, you can recurse through the local tree like this:

```
function countDescendantElements(parent) {
    var node = parent.firstChild, cnt = 0;
    while (node) {
        if (node.nodeType === 1) {
            cnt++;
            cnt += countDescendantElements(node);
        }
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
    return(cnt);
}
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kD73F/

If you just wanted to count direct children (not deeper levels) and only wanted to count element nodes (not text or comment nodes) and wanted wide browser support, you could do this:

```
function countChildElements(parent) {
    var children = parent.childNodes, cnt = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (children[i].nodeType === 1) {
            ++cnt;
        }
    }
    return(cnt);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to select all the span inside the div which will return a nodelist with all the span inside of it...
Then you can alert the length like the example below.

```js
alert(document.querySelectorAll("div span").length)
```

```html
<div>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ALTERNATIVE: If you want to count elements in a div from a browser then you do not need to write any javascript code in the console since the count is already displayed:

- Firefox:
  Right click on the div element and select 'Show DOM properties'. Then search for childElementCount and childNodes to inspect your counts.
- Chrome: Just normal click on the div element and on the side view window (where the Style is usually displayed) select the 'Properties' tab instead. The childElementCount and childNodes will be there as well.