# Selecting the last child of an element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an `<ol>` (saved to `Var1`) and would like to be able to assign its last `<li>` element to a variable.

I tried doing the following:

```js
Lastli = var1.lastChild
```

However, it doesn't seem to work.

I'd like to do this with vanilla JS, and no jQuery.

Comment: Please provide some minimum code

Comment: The reason you're not getting the last `<li>` is probably that there is some white space after its closing `</li>` tag. If you leave the closing tag out, you will be able to access it as `ul.lastChild` ;)

Comment: Thanks every one! i forgot to define it as the first ul even though it was the only Ul. `::var x = document.getElementsByClassName('listSection')[0].getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var2 = x.lastChild;
console.log(var2);`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can select the parent element and use the [`lastChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild) property.

```js
var container = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
var lastchild = container.lastChild;
```

Or you select all the items into an array and get the last item. Here is a quick example:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll("li");
var lastchild = items[items.length-1];
```

Comment: No need to select all items for the querySelector, just use `document.querySelector("li:last-child")`

Comment: To anyone using lastChild experiencing issues. Try `.lastElementChild`, it ignores text and comment nodes which could be in the way.

Answer (score 8):

you can select all 'li' and take the last one. Something like:

```
var myLi = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var lastLi = myLi[myLi.length-1];
```

Answer (score 5):

Lets consider an example

```
<ul >
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

To get the last child of the list you can simply make use of queryselector

```
document.querySelector('li:last-child'); //this will return Milk which is the last child of the list
document.querySelector('li:first-child') OR document.querySelector('li'); //both will give you the first child of the list
```

Suppose you want the n-th  child for that you can use the following syntax:

```
document.querySelector('li:nth-child(2)');  //it will return the second child (here Tea)
```

If you want all the list item in the given list:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('li') //(Will return the whole list)here i am using tagname. It can be also applied on classname or element id
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `.childNodes[childNodes.length - 1]`

Answer (score 1):

either `ulReference.children[ulReference.children.length -1]` or `ulReference.childNodes[ulReference.childNodes.length -1]`. The difference between the two can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381296/best-way-to-get-child-nodes)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the `document.querySelector` and use the `:last-child` to get it.

Exemple:

`const list = document.querySelector("li:last-child");`