# Javascript get Last DIV element in Body

Tags: javascript

If I had div's without id's or anything, but with the information that it is the last thing before the  tag, is there a way I can use javascript to delete it?
Example:

```
<body>
<div>don't delete</div>
<div>don't delete</div>
<div>don't delete</div>
<div>delete this div</div>
</body>
```

Thanks (I'm sorry if my question sucks, please tell me how I can improve it)

I also would not like to use jQuery

Comment: Duplicate: [Selecting a last child in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308906/selecting-a-last-child-in-javascript)

Comment: Eric, the duplicate doesn't have to be exact. A programmer needs to be capable of applying a (suitable) solution to a slightly different problem, or they might as well give up. The solution is `document.querySelector("body *:last-of-type").remove();` and can be inferred from the dupe.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a plain CSS selector to get the last div immediately, instead of retrieving a collection.

```js
document.querySelector('body > div:last-of-type').remove();
```

```html
<body>
  <div>don't delete</div>
  <div>don't delete</div>
  <div>don't delete</div>
  <div>delete this div</div>
</body>
```