# How ChildNode Works

Tags: javascript, nodes, getelementbyid

```
<html>
  <head>

    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
function test2() {
  var val2 = document.getElementById("ex2").childNodes[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  alert(val2);
}
--></script>

  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="ex2">Web courses - <span>http://coursesweb.net</span> - lessons, tutorials</div>
<a href="#" onclick="test2()" title="childNodes example">Test 2</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Above alerts http://coursesweb.net.

But if i add `<p>Some text</p>` and than i try to add `childNodes[2]` its not working.

Can some one please explain me this code and `ChildNode` Concept too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tracing the original query `document.getElementById("ex2").childNodes[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;` we find:

`document.getElementById("ex2")` => `<div id="ex2">Web courses -<span>http://coursesweb.net</span> - lessons, tutorials</div>`

Because the textNode "Web courses" is the first node

`.childNodes[1]` => `<span>http://coursesweb.net</span>`

`.childNodes[0]` => textNode `"http://coursesweb.net"`

`.nodeValue` => `"http://coursesweb.net"`

If you want to add `<p>Some text</p>` make your original ex2 string:

```
<div id="ex2">Web courses - <span>http://coursesweb.net</span><p>Some text</p> - lessons, tutorials</div>
```

Now
`document.getElementById("ex2").childNodes[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;` => `"Some text"`

Comment: I tried ssomething like  followingvar                              val2 = document.getElementById("ex2").childNodes[3].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  alert(val2);                                                                 result i got                                                 Web courses - http://coursesweb.net

Hi How R U?
- lessons, tutorials-
Test 2

Comment: @Swatikothari I don't see the example youre referring to can you link it to me

Comment: childNodes[3] is workimng , but childNodes[2] is not giving result

Comment: Web courses - http://coursesweb.net
Result
Hi How R U?
- lessons, tutorials-
Test 2 by pressing test2 alerts Hi How r u?

Comment: @Swatikothari http://jsfiddle.net/YY6Ug/ I set up some alerts for retrieving various elements in your html string

Comment: This means If i want to display all values one by one than i have to use loop

Comment: Its working fine with jsfiddle but in IE, Fire Fox, Opera, and in chrome its not giving alert it displaiyng correct result

Comment: @Swatikothari Explain it works for me in ff25 and chrome30 + ie9

Answer (score 1):

The childNodes property returns a collection of a node's child nodes, as a NodeList.

Tip: You can use the length property to determine the number of child nodes, then you can loop through all child nodes and extract the info you want.

In this JavaScript returns "http://coursesweb.net" because div with id ex2 have childnodes  and we get its value.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with childNodes, its content will vary whether you are on IE 8 (or less) and other browsers :

> Firefox, and most other browsers, will treat empty white-spaces or new lines as text nodes, Internet Explorer will not

http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t70

It means if you just add a space or a new line between two nodes, on some browsers the two nodes will be next to each other in childNodes, or will be separated by an empty node.

In FireFox :

```
<div>hey</div> <p>Some text</p> // childNodes[0] : hey, childNodes[1] : some text
```

does not give the same result as

```
<div>hey</div>
<p>Some text</p> // childNodes[0] : hey, childNodes[1] : nothing, childNodes[2] : some text
```

In Internet Explorer, both are the same (childNodes[0] : hey, childNodes[1] : some text)

If you can, you'd rather use jQuery .find() to dig directly to a given explicit identifier.

But if you need to introspect existing DOM tree, you need to take care of this annoying fact. see [best way to get child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381296/best-way-to-get-child-nodes)