# Checking all forms on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need to check some forms (~10) on my site.
I wrote function which will change class of inputs, so they would become red.

```
function validate() 
{
    var result = true;
    var inputList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0; i<inputList.length; i++) 
        if (inputList[i].type == 'text') 
        { 
            if(inputList[i].value == "") 
            {
                inputList[i].className='error';
                inputList[i].onchange = function() 
                {
                    this.className='';
                    resetEvents(this);
                }
                result = false;
            }
            else
            { 
                inputList[i].className='';
            } 
        }
    return result;
}
```

There are no problems with it. I checked it with some forms and it works fine. If I want form to be submitted I should add `return validate();` to onSubmit action: 
`<form class='form' id='form' action='' method='post' onSubmit='return validate()'>` 
Now I need to set onSubmit-actions of all forms.

I want to assign forms handler on page loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var formList = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for (var i=0; i < formList.length; i++) 
            formList[i].onsubmit = return validate();
}
```

This code don't work, because of `return validate();`, but if I remove `return` and will just assign handler all inputs would be with .error class already on page load.

What I have to make this working correct?

Comment: Just a tip. If you are looping through controls and jQuery most likely you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign the function reference to the onsubmit handler, not the value returned by validate method

```
formList[i].onsubmit = validate; //this inside validate will refer to the submitted form
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TY4EC/)

But I will prefer to use jQuery submit handler(`this` inside the validate method will refer to the clicked form)

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('form').submit(validate)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XXYrv/)

Note: it has one drawback, that is since you are returning `false` from validate it will prevent both the default action and the propagation of the submit event.

Comment: Default return for function validate is true, not false, it become false only if at least 1 blank field found. Your code let submit blank form without any edits. I added `function validate()` in my question. @Arun P Johny

Comment: Form not submitting only if all fields are blank. If at least 1 field filled form may be submitted. It's not correct. @Arun P Johny