# What is the best practice to get a child of an element in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Something like get an variable out of class.

```
ParentElement.someId.someId..
```

If i have something like that in css:

```
#someId #aaa #bbb
{
    ...
}

#someOtherId #aaa #bbb
{
    ...
}
```

and i want to get only the element under "#someId".
Something like

```
getElementById("someId aaa bbb");
```

would be great, unfortunately this one doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah but there is this situation ( updated the question )

Comment: But...ID is still supposed to be unique within the page. If you need to make the distinction that your CSS does then your html is invalid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [best way to get child nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381296/best-way-to-get-child-nodes)

Answer (score 0):

If you have given an `id` to the element, you can say

```
document.getElementById(childId)
```

> Id must be unique in the document.

In your scenario, what I think you are having element with same `Id` at multiple places. Either you can user `class` instead of `id`.

Comment: Exactly, i'm trying to avoid names like "some_button", "other_button" "one_more_button". i want one "button" class/id to be under different divs inside the document. I know i cab have references if i "spawning" them by code, but i don't want to be have to".

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get the element in javascript, or what do you mean by "getting" in HTML?

```
<div id="box">
    <div>Child element</div>
    <div>Child element</div>
</div>
```

You can access a specific element by `getElementById('box');` and you can access its children by `getElementById('box').children`. So the first child would be `getElementById('box').children[0]` for example.

Did that help you ?

Comment: I Prefer not to use numbers for the sake of order. something like getElementById('box').children["name"] would be great.

Comment: You could use jQuery if that is an option to you. There you can easily select a child element like this: `$('#someID .aaa');` (use classes for the sub elements because ids have to be unique on the whole page)

Comment: If this JQuery line works i think this is exactly what i needed! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Id's are unique within the document so your `ParentElement.someId.someId` can simply be translated to `document.getElementById(childId)`.

Regarding the sample `CSS` you posted, please note that you cannot have both situations in the same `HTML` at the same time, you can stylise differently based on the `DOM` hierarchy though. With this in mind, you can use the same `document.getElementById(childId)` call.

Answer (score 0):

ID should be unique, so you really shouldn't have elements with the same ID over and over, instead you can use `class`.

To access the element though, first you get the parent:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("someId");
```

Then use querySelector on parent to get the desired element:

```
var element = parent.querySelector('.ELEMENT_CLASS');
```

And if it's id then:

```
var element = parent.querySelector('#ELEMENT_ID');
```