# Access child elements generated by a template

Tags: javascript, html

In my application I'm generating HTML with a Go template. I pass a list to a template that resembles this:

```
<div id="myList">
 {{ Loop }}
   <div id="{{.loopIndex}}">
 {{ End loop }}
</div>
```

I now want to access the individual children in JavaScript according to ID. These are not 'elements', so I can't use the HTML DOM getAttribute() method, or access element.id.

I want to do something like this:

```
  var listElement = document.getElementById("myList");
  var listElements = listElement.childNodes;

  for (i=0; i < listElements.length; i++) {
     alert(listElements[i].id);
  }
```

How would I do this? Is there any way to convert the objects in my list to DOM Elements? The example I gave is a lot simpler than my actual code, but it would follow the same approach, I imagine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [best way to get child nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381296/best-way-to-get-child-nodes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `getElementsByTagName`:

```js
var listElement = document.getElementById("myList");
var listElements = listElement.getElementsByTagName('div'); // could also use listElement.children;

for (i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++) {
  alert(listElements[i].id);
}
```

```html
<div id="myList">
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="3"></div>
</div>
```

Or just `children`:

```
var listElements = listElement.children;
```

Comment: I forgot about getElementsByTagName, I'm sure this will work just great!

Answer (score 0):

After retrieving the list element with `document.getElementById('myList')` and assigning it to `list`, you can retrieve its children with `list.getElementById(n)` where `n` is the `id`. (Or you could continue to use `document.getElementById` if the element IDs are unique in the document, as they are supposed to be.)

Demonstration:

```js
function print(s) {
  document.write(s + '<br />');
}

var list = document.getElementById('myList');
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
  var child = list.getElementById(i);
  print(child.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div id="myList">
  <div id="1"> one </div>
  <div id="2"> two </div>
  <div id="3"> three </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A good approach but unfortunately I will not know the content of the list or size, which makes this solution limited.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with [document.querySelector](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_queryselectorall.asp), works fine with `all browsers` and `ie 9`

[See a demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deFreitas/2fejd5ff/)

```js
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#myList .list-item");
  for(var i=0; i < listItems.length; i++){
    console.info(listItems[i].id);
}
```

```html
<div id="myList">
  <div class="list-item" id="1" >item 1</div>
  <div class="list-item" id="2" >item 2</div>
  <div class="list-item" id="3" >item 3</div>
</div>
```