# Why can't I select nodes child by document.getElementById("node's_id").child?

Tags: javascript, dom, parent-child, nodes

Suppose I have a simple html code sonsisiting a parent `div` and child `span` element as:

`<div id="my_div"><span>  Nothin' but the G thang  </span></div>`

It is said that every element in html DOM is an object. So we can select child objects as `parent.child`. E.g. `window.document`, `window.document.body`, `window.document.head` etc then my question is why does `document.getElementById("my_div").span` return undefined?

Similarly `window.document.body` works but I can't go one level down after that with `window.document.body.div`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [best way to get child nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381296/best-way-to-get-child-nodes).

Comment: @FreemanLambda `.span`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `.`(`dot-notation`), you are trying to access the `span` property of the `object`(`Node/Element`) returned by `document.getElementById`. As there is no `span` property associated with returned object, `document.getElementById("my_div").span` will be `undefined`

Use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), *Returns the first element within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes|by first element in document markup and iterating through sequential nodes by order of amount of child nodes) that matches the specified group of selectors*

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#my_div span'));
```

```html
<div id="my_div"><span>  Nothin' but the G thang  </span>
</div>
```

Or [`Node.chilren`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children), *read-only property that returns a live HTMLCollection of the child elements of Node.*

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('my_div').children[0]);
```

```html
<div id="my_div"><span>  Nothin' but the G thang  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: And without extra JS stuff, getElementsByTagName would work once you have the parent element

Comment: @zerohero, There are `n` number of ways! And there is not extra stuff required for `querySelector`

Comment: Are `head` and `body` tags properties or objects in the DOM?

Comment: Yes, `head` and `body` are properties of `document` object!

Comment: Could you give a reference because w3school claim otherwise http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_head.asp

Comment: `typeof document.head` and `typeof document.body` return `"object"`.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the answer _"you are trying to access the span property of the object"_... It is of type object....You could say `documentObject`

Comment: Perhaps I got you. `head` and `body` objects are properties of `document object`.

Comment: Glad to help you mate !

Answer (score 2):

You can select span like this

```js
var span = document.getElementById("my_div").querySelector('span');
console.log(span);
```

```html
<div id="my_div"><span>  Nothin' but the G thang  </span>
</div>
```

Or in your case you can also use `firstChild`

```js
var span = document.getElementById("my_div").firstChild;
console.log(span);
```

```html
<div id="my_div"><span>Nothin' but the G thang  </span></div>
```

Comment: I've edited the question. I am not asking how to select the child. I am asking why can't I select it as `document.getElementById("my_div").span`?

Comment: Yes it returns object but there is no span property inside https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/609/ here is a list of all properties https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/610/