# javascript How to get a text from div inside li list

Tags: javascript

I have a ul list inside which li is there, and inside li text and div are there. the same class is assigned to li while div is assigned with a different class name.

I just want to get the text from div and not from li.

Just need to get the "**I need this text 112**" from the div. I am trying:

```js
li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
```

```html
<ul class="category">
  <li class="hero" href="page1.htm">
    <a href="page1.htm"><img src="img/001.png" /></a>
    <div class="Hello">
      <a href="page1.htm">I need this text&nbsp;112</a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

But it gives me an error.

Comment: If you want text from a `div`, shouldn't your code refer to a `div`?  If you want text, shouldn't your code say something about text?

Comment: Try it: var child = ul.children[0].children[1]; [Best way to get child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381296/best-way-to-get-child-nodes)

Comment: @QuockhanhPham `children` isn't the best way to get child *nodes*. It's the best way to get child *elements*. But the OP's starting point is the `ul`, the `a` isn't a child. You're missing at least one level in your example there, and doing things like chained `children` with hardcoded indexes is brittle. `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` is almost always the better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelector` to find the element from the `document` or, if you already have a reference to the `ul`, you can use that as a starting point.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".category li div.Hello a");
// or var elem = ul.querySelector("li div.Hello a")
alert(elem.textContent)
```

```html
<ul class="category">
<li class="hero" href="page1.htm">
    <a href="page1.htm"><img src="img/001.png"></a>
    <div class="Hello">
        <a href="page1.htm">I need this text</a>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Some kind of explanation as to why this works would be nice.

Comment: it gives me an error
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null"

Comment: is this jquery or pure javascript?

Comment: @Mrquestion no jquery here, just pure JS

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) passing it a string containing any valid CSS selector, and it will return a reference to the first matching element. There's also [`Element#querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) which does the same thing when your starting point is an element (as yours appears to be, your `ul`). Once you have the element, [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is probably your best way to get the text now, although you could also use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) on some browsers. (You can also use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) — on any browser — if you want the HTML, not just the text.) So for instance:

```
text = ul.querySelector(".hello a").textContent;
```

If there may be multiple matches and you don't want the first, get a list from `querySelectorAll` (on [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [on elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)) instead.