# Separate text and children in a HTML node in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

In JavaScript, I would like to split a node to separate text and children. Consider the following node:

```
<p>text <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i></p>
```

I would like to get an array (or something iterable) that looks like:

1. `"text" => text`
2. `<b>bold</b> => child`
3. `"and" => text`
4. `<i>italic</i> => child`

How to do this in an efficient and elegant way?

Comment: What does "elegant" mean to you? You can already get all of this information via `document.querySelector('p').childNodes`; you would just need to examine the `nodeType` to see if the child is a `textNode`.

Comment: Elegant means 'nice and short'. Your answer is perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to get child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381296/best-way-to-get-child-nodes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get an array of text/HTML for each child node, you can run the children through a switch-statement and check the node type.

***Note:*** Here are all the [nodeTypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).

```js
const nodeText = (nodes) => {
  return Array.from(nodes).map(node => {
    switch (node.nodeType) {
      case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        return node.textContent.trim();
      case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        return node.outerHTML;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }).filter(text => text != null);
}

console.log(nodeText(document.querySelector('p').childNodes));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<p>text <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i></p>
```